# Stacking Tables for a responsive HTML email

Tags: html, html-table, html-email

New to this email stuff, but I've searched and searched for days, and still cannot crack this one. I want the two images to stack when shrinking the window and the BG to turn orange as I have it below. I have a feeling it's something in the way I have the tables are nested.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
                .content {
                    background-color: #DF6618;
                    width: 100% !important;
                    height: auto !important;
                }

                .contentSmall {
                    width: 100%;
                    height: auto;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>

        <table width="600px" class="content">
             <tr>
                 <td>
                     <table width="300px" class="contentSmall">
                         <tr>
                             <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_FkAI_ee_eBA/SASnSymg3fI/AAAAAAAAAIA/E6UODcxSoTY/s400/300px-Helix_nebula.jpg"; width="300"; border="1px";/>
                         </tr>
                     </table>
                 </td>

                 <td>
                     <table width="300px" class="contentSmall">
                         <tr>
                             <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_FkAI_ee_eBA/SASnSymg3fI/AAAAAAAAAIA/E6UODcxSoTY/s400/300px-Helix_nebula.jpg"; width="300"; border="1px";/>
                         </tr>
                     </table>
                 </td>
            </tr>
        </table>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all, I would look into HTML semantics. Images are not tabular data and should not be used inside a table. I strongly recommend that you take a look at bootstrap and supply the necessary additional rules using your own media queries.

Comment: I would definitely not use bootstrap for email.

Comment: Since you are "new to this email stuff," I would check out [this chart](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) which shows what features are supported in HTML emails by different clients.  For example, all of your styles will be nuked by Gmail because they are in a `<head>` section.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. I think bootstrap would be overkill for this. Also, since I can't even get these to stack in my browser, I think it's too early to look at email client issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the table elements display properties to block, like so:

```
        @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
            .content {
                background-color: #DF6618;
                width: 100% !important;
                height: auto !important;
            }
            table, tbody, tr, th, td {
                display: block
            }
            .contentSmall {
                width: 100%;
                height: auto;
            }
        }
```

You could also try taking a look at [Zurb Ink](http://zurb.com/ink/) for a responsive email framework. Here's some [templates](https://github.com/sendwithus/templates) you could try modifying too.